# Should this question be migrated to the programme's stack exhange

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, migration, site-recommendation, software-engineering-se

It is to my understanding that programmers stack exchange is "a question and answer site for professionals and students in software development" that are asking "conceptual questions about software development" (2 minute tour of site). I have a more conceptual question on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25418308/performance-check-for-empty-array-or-allow-iteration

Is this question 'conceptual' enough to be migrated to programmers?

Comment: Try asking on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Can I get this question on migration migrated to Meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: Or meta.programmers.

Comment: @MrLister you need 5 rep on the main site to post on the meta.

Comment: As written, the question on SO seems to fall into one of: unclear, too broad, or unanswerable.  It wouldn't fare well in its current form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it should stay where it is since the current format of the question is too broad for either of the sites (and therefore should be put on hold / closed).

A question that demands an answer on language implementation specifics must have a language tag at least, probably even a version number since it may change over time. How would you think .NET / C# compares to C, or Swift, or PL/SQL? Giving a conclusive answer would take pages, hence the 'too broad' close reason applies:

> There are either **too many possible answers**, or good answers would be **too long for this format**. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll narrow the languages and versions.