# Why don't site-specific questions just get migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration, meta

There's a close reason:

> This question pertains only to a specific site in the Stack Exchange Network. Questions on Meta Stack Exchange should pertain to our network or software that drives it as a whole, within the guidelines defined in the help center. You should ask this question on the meta site where your concern originated.

Why don't questions like these just get migrated to the proper meta?

Examples:

- [Should this question be migrated to the programme's stack exhange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238602/259693)
- [Ask Different Name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239022/259693)
- [Why are "bug report" questions considered offtopic only at Ask Ubuntu?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238672/259693)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no migration paths set up to migrate questions from Meta Stack Exchange to other Metas. Regular users cannot vote to migrate from here to other sites. If this were enabled, there would be over 100 sites to choose from. It's easier to just have one message that tells the OP to ask on the site where they came from. This way it doesn't require a moderator to intervene.

Answer (score 4):

For the specific questions you cite, none of the users who voted to close the question are Moderators. Since only Moderators can migrate questions to per-site metas, and none were involved, the questions were simply closed.

I expect that no Moderators were involved because no one alerted a Moderator that their assistance was necessary. I suppose if someone had used the "Other" reason for a question flag to say "this is an excellent question that should be migrated to {site}'s meta" a Moderator may have done so.

That said, of course, the Golden Rule of Migrations is "*Don't migrate crap*." I don't see anything so compelling on any of those questions that it *must* be migrated straight away.